# React- Unable to change state from child component using function defined within a container component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my container component:

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Search from '../components/Search';
import Weather from '../components/Weather';
import Location from '../components/Location';
import 'tachyons';


const api = {
  key: '1e96cf99930c0192bd53fe21fa67fbc1',
  base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
}


const App = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('q');
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});


  const getWeather = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      setQuery(e.target.value);
      fetch(`${api.base}?q=${query}&units=imperial&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          setWeather(data);
          setQuery('');
          console.log(data);
        });
    }
  }


  return (
    <div className="app tc">
      <div className="search-box">
        <Search getWeather={getWeather} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my child component:

```
import React from 'react';


const Search = ({ getWeather }) => {
  return (
    <input type="search" className="search-bar" onKeyPress={getWeather} />
  );
}

export default Search;
```

I am having an issue where even though the getWeather function runs on key press, it's not changing the state of weather or query. What am I doing wrong in case?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: use onchange to get your input value and onkeypress to submit

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the conclusion that it may be because I'm changing the state within the same if statement - and since this runs asynchronously (?), I'm guessing the CHANGED state is not actually being passed into the fetch statement..?

Comment: you are set query inside getWeather move it to search component

Comment: So I followed yalls advice and just added another function inside the parent component that sets query state to event.target.value

And inside Search component, I'm having it set the query onChange (so everytime a user inputs or deletes something..) and it works fine - but is there a more efficient way of doing this? It seems like changing the state every time the user inputs something may be redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the query when pressing enter. Move it to search component and update the value there.

```
const Search = ({ getWeather, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <input type="search" onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} className="search-bar" onKeyPress={getWeather} />
  );
}
```

In your search component do, and remove setQuery from getWeather.

```
<Search onChange={setQuery} getWeather={getWeather} />
```

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const api = {
  key: '1e96cf99930c0192bd53fe21fa67fbc1',
  base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
}

    const Search = ({ getWeather, onChange }) => {
      return (
        <input type="search" onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} className="search-bar" onKeyPress={getWeather} />
      );
    }

function App(){
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('q');
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});


  const getWeather = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      fetch(`${api.base}?q=${query}&units=imperial&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          setWeather(data);
          setQuery('');
          console.log(data);
        });
    }
  }


  return (
    <div className="app tc">
      <div className="search-box">
        <Search onChange={setQuery} getWeather={getWeather} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```